# Change file name into Title Case in buk

Tags: powershell

I have bulk image files that I want to change their filenames into Title Case via PowerShell.

For example:

> file name like this.jpg

To:

> File Name Like This.jpg

I have 700+ files in sub folders.
I have tried this code:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\new" -recurse |Where {-Not $_.PSIsContainer} |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName.TOUPPER()}
```

But this code capitalizes all letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So PowerShell actually has a super simple way to do that using `Get-Culture`'s textinfo. That property contains a method called `ToTitleCase()` which will do exactly (almost) what you want. The only difference being that it will also capitalize the 'J' in 'Jpg'. Just the extension though, so no big deal right?

```
$Culture = Get-Culture
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\new" -recurse |Where {-Not $_.PSIsContainer} |Rename-Item -NewName {$Culture.textinfo.totitlecase($_.FullName)}
```

Comment: And if you need it to not change the J in jpg you could try `-NewName { [regex]::Replace($_.FullName, '(^| ).', {"$args".ToUpper()}) }`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks this code work ....  For 'J' im using this code PS C:\temp\new> Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.J*" -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace `.J','.j' }  anyways thanks again ..

Comment: When your files are already in UPPERCASE, you need to use `toLower()` method before `{$Culture.textinfo.totitlecase..`. Hope it helps someone.